# How to substitute Table environments by a more sophisticated code

Tags: list-manipulation

I often use Tables inside of Tables to fill 2 dimensional arrays.

Is it possible for the lower example code to substitute the Table environments by a more sophisticated and shorter code?

```
list1 = Range[1, 10]; 
list2 = Range[11, 20]; 

n1 = Length[list1]; 
n2 = Length[list2]; 

result = Array[0 &, {n1, n2}]; 

Table[
  Table[
    result[[c1, c2]] = list1[[c1]] + list2[[c2]], 
    {c1, 1, n1}
  ], 
  {c2, 1, n2}
]
```

Comment: `list2 + # & /@ list1`?

Comment: great ... thank you. This is what I was looking for. Probably that can be extended for more than two Table loops: for 3 Tables `list3 + # & /@ list2 + # & /@ list1`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Outer[Plus, Range[1, 10], Range[11, 20]]
```

Comment: This is awesome ... I vote for this.

Answer (score 3):

Using your current variables, you can substitute both of your tables with just one table by using the code below:

```
list1 = Range[1, 10]; 
list2 = Range[11, 20]; 

n1 = Length[list1]; 
n2 = Length[list2];

result = Array[0 &, {n1, n2}];

Table[result[[c1, c2]] = list1[[c1]] + list2[[c2]], {c1, 1, n1}, {c2, 1, n2}]
```

The reason that this is possible is that `Table` can actually take in multiple arguments for loops and will treat it like you did using multiple `Table`s.

I hope this helped to answer your question.

EDIT: I would comment, except I don't have enough points yet, but John Doty's answer is much better.

Comment: this makes the code much shorter, when even more Tables are present ... thanks

Comment: yay, glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Partition[#, 10, 1] & @ Range[12, 30]
```

> {{12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21}, {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
>     19, 20, 21, 22}, {14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23}, {15, 16, 
>     17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24}, {16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 
>     24, 25}, {17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26}, {18, 19, 20, 21, 
>     22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27}, {19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
>     28}, {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29}, {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
>     26, 27, 28, 29, 30}}

```
Partition[#, 10, 1] &@Range[12, 30] == 
Table[Table[result[[c1, c2]] = list1[[c1]] + list2[[c2]], {c1, 1, n1}], {c2, 1,n2}]
```

> True